# Can't Fill Form on Instagram

Tags: javascript, web, imacros

I want to fill the form with my code but the form can't be filled like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Miwpg.jpg)

my code imacros for fill like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX 
TAB T=1 URL GOTO=https://www.instagram.com/ 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:emailOrPhone CONTENT=natsudipta17@gmail.com 
WAIT SECONDS=1 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:fullName CONTENT=anjir<SP>anjir 
WAIT SECONDS=1 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=Aseow17222 
WAIT SECONDS=1 
SET !ENCRYPTION NO 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=abegoboga123 
WAIT SECONDS=1 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>up
```

Please help me to fix this problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to record your macro with '**Experimental event recording mode**'.

 Or just play the following code:

```
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.instagram.com/ 
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
SET !REPLAYSPEED MEDIUM
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="form input[name='emailOrPhone']" CHARS="natsudipta17@gmail.com"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="form input[name='fullName']" CHARS="anjir anjir"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="form input[name='username']" CHARS="Aseow17222"
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="form input[name='password']" CHARS="abegoboga123"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>up
```